# Find the coefficient of $ x^6 y^8 $in the expansion of:

Tags: binomial-theorem

Find the coefficient of $x^6 y^8$ in the expansion of: 
$$\left(4x+\frac{y}{2}\right)^{14}$$

Answer (score 4):

Apply 
$$(a + b)^n =\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} a^k b^{n-k}.$$
For which $k$ do you get an $x^6y^8$ term?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Write $$\left(4x + \frac{1}{2}y\right)^{14} = \sum_{i=0}^{14} \binom{14}{i} (4x)^i \left(\frac{1}{2}y\right)^{14-i}$$